# Fragment dynamic ui restoration onStop()

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I'm a little confused as to how to save a fragment's current UI when say for example, I navigate to another app and come back to my app. I have a fragment where you can dynamically add views on click of a button, as well as a timer that may or may not be active, depending on the user. Dynamically added views may or may not be removed depending on the user as well. Basically, I want to save all the views that are currently on the screen, as well as the countdown timer and the current time it is at whenever I navigate outside of my app, which I'm assuming is when onStop() is called. How would I go about doing this? I'm a little confused as to the saving process and how I would restore my data.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you need to save. Are we talking indexs, ints, entire objects, or images etc..

Your question is a little vague, but there are many ways to store data.
First thing to remember is that however, the UI looked when you return will be how it still looks. If you are losing your UI on return, you are probably doing something wrong.

Now if you are returning after the app has been destroyed or you have no history flags set to avoid it retaining UI or garbage collection just took back your memory space and killed your app, then you will go through onPause and onStop and onDestroy.

You may choose to save your data in sharedPref (if it is not secure)
You may choose to save your data in SecureSharedPref (custom file, encrypts, but not hidden from file system)
You may choose to save your data in SQLite database, you will need SQLOpenHelper implementation.
Or if you are returning to the app while it is still alive you may use save in bundle to restore in onCreate like

```
   @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString(MY_KEY, mMyvalue);

    // call superclass to save any view hierarchy
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

This is restored in the bundle of onCreate so you would need to see if the keys exist in the returned bundle on next onCreate call. However, this does not persist between destroyed sessions, this only persists as long as your app has not been cleared from memory. Also to use this you must use parcable objects that are serializable. All you have to do is implement it and you are good to go.

Comment: To clarify, the views that I am dynamically adding contain edittexts that take in text/numbers as input. So I need to save these text/numbers. However, the user can press a button which will either reduce these numbers or start a timer (the timer is displayed as ints in an edittext). When the user finishes inflating a x number of views, they are required to save, which will save all the views created to a sqlite database. The issue that I have is getting the current ui to restore since view data will constantly be changing.

Comment: Also, the current ui restores if I hold down the home button and switch applications from there. However, if I press home, and switch applications, it disappears.

Comment: So just store a list of values. You can put an entire serializable array into it of objects or you can loop through and store a key/value for each item in the list with an iterator. As for restoring, are you setting no history flags in your manifest. Make sure you don't have any intent flags set that you don't recognize in your manifest.